# Nothing running after loading weights with training checkpoints

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to load weights from checkpoints after training a model and then stopping before end of training (still lots of steps). I seem to be able to load the weights by doing:

```
latest = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir)
model.load_weights(latest)
```

The checkpoint dir has files like [checpoint, ckpt-44.data-00000-of-00001, ckpt-44.inde, ...] and by running the load weights I get a bunch af arrays that seem to be the weights as output but also warning (just a portion of the warning):

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'v' for (root).model.layer_with_weights-86.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'v' for (root).model.layer_with_weights-86.bias
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'v' for (root).model.layer_with_weights-87.alpha
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'v' for (root).model.layer_with_weights-88.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'v' for (root).model.layer_with_weights-88.bias
```

and after this has run the program just ends. Nothing else is run. If I try to print or show image after this then nothing happens (or if I try to do what I actually want to do). Does anybody have any idea what is happening? Thanks and sorry if similar, have not seen and will remove if I find similar.

I tried a bunch of different ways to load the checkpoint and they didn't seem to work but this seems to load it but not let me do much after loading. I was expecting to be able to continue training or do what I want with the loaded weights.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make predictions after loading weights from the check points file which has a checkpoint for each epoch

```
latest = tf.train.latest_checkpoint('/content/training')
model1.load_weights(latest)
```

For complete code you can refer to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/kiransair/4ce62d976d2f490c9981b0eda9eabb31). Thank You,